# Adding references when using in MonoDevelop when using MonoDroid

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin.android

I have only just started experimenting with MonoDroid and this is my first time using Mono and MonoDevelop. I wanted to do some Json stuff and added a reference to ServiceStack.Text library. However, the namespaces in the newly added assembly references are not available in the intellisense until I restart MonoDevelop. Has anyone else encountered this? I can't quite tell if this is a MonoDevelop issue or something more specific to the MonoDroid/MonoDevelop combination.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to Mono for Android somehow. I tired recreating your test case, which seemed as you described with a Mono for Android project. Creating a similar project just for MonoTouch, it loads the IntelliSense immediately not having to restart MonoDevelop. I suggest you file a bug in their BugZilla: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/index.cgi